# Estimate electromagnetic emission due to current in wire

Tags: power, wire, electromagnetic, emissions

I am working on a project that will need to pass CEM requirements.

I would like to "estimate", as in, get an order of magnitude of the electromagnetic emission.
The device include 2 parts. The output of the first part is connected to the input of second by 2 wires.
A 5amps, 230V, 20kHz signal is going through these wires. Wires are "classic" copper 1.5mm2. The length is yet to be determined.

Is there a "simple" way to estime the EM radiation (V/m and T) of the wires from the above numbers?

The goal would be to estimate the maximum length to stay within regulation.

Comment: Simpliticy depends on your signal. Is the 20kHz 5A 230V signal a sine wave or square wave, or some other waveform?

Comment: it's 50Hz sine wave hashed at 20kHz. But I am open to simplifying assumption that would be a worse case than the one described here. Like in the case of square or sine wave at 50kHz

Comment: If you're chopping a waveform then you don't have a 20 KHz signal but something higher. You should figure out what that is, a 100 KHz signal will radiate a lot less then a 10 MHz signal. Obviously designing your chopper to minimize it's frequency is a good idea.

Comment: "Estimate" is difficult. Trying is one "solution". 1- Get a "LISN" and measure "conducted" radiations ... 2- If one can have a wideband "directional antenna and a "spectrum analyzer", go in "open air" (where no reflections ... ) and measure by "difference" (when no emissions, device switched off, and when "emissions occurs, device switched on. "Subtract" the results, one have a little idea).

Comment: The radiation due to the 20 kHz signal will not be the problem. The problem will be the common mode RF current flowing on the wires (arising from high-speed digital clocks or data). This can easily be mitigated with common-mode chokes on the source side. In reality the wires can probably be as long as you want. 100 meters or more. Any problems you encounter will be from things you have not even mentioned in your question.

Comment: Slew rate control on the rising and falling edges of the 20 kHz signal will definitely help minimize emissions at 20 kHz and harmonics.

Comment: Thanks for all comments.
So if I understand correctly a signal at 20kHz or even 100kHz will not radiate much. The problem will arise from the dv/dt to go from 0 to 230V (which is 230V/ 200ns) and all other parasitic signal going trough that wire itself ?

Comment: I have been thinking about this. I have never tried to certify something with such high voltage swing (50 V @ 20 kHz yes, but not 220 V). Still, I think you will be able to pass if you are willing and able to put ferrite cores on the cable at the source end. It would be better if you could use shielded cable or coax, but maybe that is not possible for your application. 200 ns sounds pretty fast.

Comment: I usually fail from a processor clock or something radiating out on a cable in common mode.

Comment: Ok super interesting, so it is usually not the 20kHz itself the problem but rather other signals on that same wire.
I can indeed add ferrite cores or shielded cable. Just need to check price and availability for this parameters

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not even close to being possible due to the unknown variables. If you were asking regards conducted emissions then I'd say yes, it's reasonably possible.

The problem is the length of the wire and, how fast the 50 Hz is being switched and, at what frequency a simple wire turns into a fine little antenna that sprays EM all over the place. It's down to rise and fall times of the switching of the 50 Hz.

It's also down to the type of interconnecting wire, the conductor spacing and whether there are twists and a cable shield that is adequately earthed.

> *Is there a "simple" way to estime the EM radiation (V/m and T)*

No I don't think anything will be accurate. BTW, normally the magnetic part of field is specified in amps/metre and not flux density (teslas).

Comment: Ok that is sad. Conducted emissions are in fact almost entirely predictable (using theoretical ideal model at least) and I have done that.
Why is that so impossible ? EM equations should solvable in such regime and approximation about conductor spacing can be made and I know the speed of switching.

Comment: All I can say is that I have tried and failed and got nowhere near close due to the variables I mentioned and, there are probably more things to consider like the disposition of the earth plane, the enclosures of the two units interacting with said earth plane and the shape of the enclosures becoming antennas in their own right. A real tricky problem that maybe a very expensive RF field simulator could get to within 10 dB of reality.